# Level by level traversal of parent array n-ary tree?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, tree

Given an n-ary tree stored in a parent array, with the children stored in an array of pointers to arrays where the first value is the number of children:

(childArray[2][0] shows that node 2 has 2 children, childArray[2][1] shows that its first child is 5, etc.)

```
parentArray = {3, 0, 3, -1, 3, 2, 2};
childArray = {{1, 1}, {0}, {2, 5, 6}, {3, 0, 2, 4}, {0}, {0}, {0}};
```

produces a tree that looks like this:

```
  3
 /|\
0 2 4
| |\
1 5 6
```

Using a queue, how can I output the tree level by level like so:

Level 1: 3

Level 2: 0, 2, 4

Level 3: 1, 5, 6

Levels 1 and 2 are easy, because level 1 is just the root and level 2 is just its children, but after that I can't figure out how to get it to get the children of the children.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is homework.

Comment: Hint: if that is a university assignment I would just hint at trying to find a way to push into the queue some special value that say something like: end-of-level.

Comment: homework is not always detached from real programming challenges.

Comment: The assignment is already completed and turned in, this was just an option for extra credit that I couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing so would be using a [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28abstract_data_type%29) data structure.

Start with some queue *q*, and place in the index of the (unique) item whose parent is -1. Now, at each step, until *q* is empty,

- Perform *v <- pop(q)* (popping the head)
- Print out *v*
- For each child *w* of *v*, do *push(q, v)* (pushing ot the tail)

For example, here are the first steps for your case:

- Initially, *q = [3]* (3 is the index of the item whose parent is -1).
- We pop *q*, print out 3, and push 0, 2, and 4, so *q = [0, 2, 4]*.
- Now we pop *q*, print out 0, and push 1, so *q = [2, 4, 1]*.

Almost by definition, since *q* is popped from the front and added to the back, the nodes will be processed level by level.

The complexity is linear in the number of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to perform a [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (Breadth First Search) on the tree, while maintaining the number of nodes pushed into the next level. Outline:

```
q.push(root); nodesInCurrentLevel = 1; nodesInNextLevel = 0; currentLevelIndex = 1;
while q is not empty do:
  u = q.pop()
  print currentLevelIndex and u
  decrement nodesInCurrentLevel
  for every child v of u do:
    increment nodesInNextLevel
    q.push(v)
  if nodesInCurrentLevel is 0 do:
    nodesInCurrentLevel = nodesInNextLevel
    nodesInNextLevel = 0
    increment currentLevelIndex
```

Of course, this would print the output as Level 2:0 Level 2:2, etc. You can store current level nodes in a temporary list within the loop and print as appropriate.